# Entity Framework 6, Fluent API - many-to-many relationship

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

I am using EF 6.4.4 in an ASP.NET MVC 4 application and am trying to model some SQL using Fluent API a many-to-many relationship with a join table. The SQL I am trying to duplicate is as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA ta
LEFT JOIN joinTable jt ON ta.ID = jt.TAID
LEFT JOIN tableB tb ON jt.TBID = tb.ID
```

The fluent that I am trying to use is:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<tableA>()
            .HasMany(t => tableB)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(m =>
            {
               m.ToTable("joinTable");
               m.MapLeftKey("TAID");
               m.MapRightKey("TBID");
            });
```

The code compiles, but when I run the application, it throws an exception

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation

If I comment out the fluent and use straight LINQ (`from a in tableA....`) it works, but I have to code the joins.

Has anyone an idea why this may not be working?

Regards.

Comment: I don't think this works if you have actually defined joinTable in your context, which you will have had to do to do the join manually.  If you have defined joinTable then remove it then try this again.

Also your WithMany should probably be `WithMany(t => t.tableA)`.

Try pasting the FULL exception message, it should tell you what the validation errors actually were.

Comment: Thanks, I upgraded an earlier version of EF to EF6, this bit would not work. Putting anything in the WithMany() statement also, would not work.  For now, I have just replaced it with a normal query and join.